# Print binary matches only with sed?

Tags: regex, sed, character-encoding, binaryfiles

Let's first have a binary test file:

```
echo -e '\x00\x01\x00\x0a\x00\x0f\x32\x7a\xb0\x00\x00\x01' > test.bin

hexdump -C test.bin 
# 00000000  00 01 00 0a 00 0f 32 7a  b0 00 00 01 0a           |......2z.....|
# 0000000d
```

Now let's see if I can match the bytes' sequence 0x0f 0x32 0x7a with `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/\(\x0f\x32\x7a\)/\1/p' test.bin | hexdump -C
# 00000000  00 0f 32 7a b0 00 00 01  0a                       |..2z.....|
# 00000009
```

That works as expected - the printed match is from the last linefeed 0x0a to the <s>next one</s> end. Now, I want to print the match only - first I try to filter out with `.*` regex at start:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(\x0f\x32\x7a\)/\1/p' test.bin | hexdump -C
# 00000000  0f 32 7a b0 00 00 01 0a                           |.2z.....|
# 00000008
```

That works - now let's do the same, but also for the trailing part:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(\x0f\x32\x7a\).*/\1/p' test.bin | hexdump -C
# 00000000  0f 32 7a b0 00 00 01 0a                           |.2z.....|
# 00000008
```

Well, that does *not* work - only the heading part is removed - but the trailing part keeps going, even if I also terminated my `sed` match pattern with `.*` ??!

What is going on here - and how can I get `sed` to print out only the bytes 0x0f 0x32 0x7a on output (taking into account that <s>`hexdump`</s> `sed` will add the final linefeed 0x0a, when it prints a match)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting.  Here's a simpler repro case:

```
echo -en '\xff\x80' | sed -n 's/\xff.*/!/p' | hexdump -C
```

The above prints `21 80` which is `!\x80`.  The `\x80` can be a larger ASCII code too, but it cannot be smaller: `\x7F` has `sed` doing the expected thing, printing only the `!`.

Also check out what this does:

```
echo -en '\xff\x80' | sed -n 's/\xff./!/p' | hexdump -C
```

It prints nothing at all.

So the question becomes, what's special about `\x80` and higher?  Well, [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) of course!  In UTF-8, having the first bit of a code point set indicates more bytes are coming.  And `sed` never finds them, so it never interprets the character at all.

If you want to "fix" it, tell `sed` to use the "good old" C locale:

```
LC_ALL=C sed ...
```

Then you get your expected output:

```
echo -e '\x00\x01\x00\x0a\x00\x0f\x32\x7a\xb0\x00\x00\x01' |
  LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/.*\(\x0f\x32\x7a\).*/\1/p' |
  hexdump -C

00000000  0f 32 7a 0a                                       |.2z.|
```

Comment: Fantastic, @JohnZwinck - many thanks for this; would never have guessed this has to do with byte ranges and UTF-8. Cheers!